# Rerun nuxt route middleware if store getter changes without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

Given following middleware, whats the best way to rerun the logic when ever `store.getters.authenticated` changes, and not only on the initial load.

***middleware/auth.js***

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.getters.authenticated) {
    return redirect({ name: "login" })
  }
}
```

Comment: Since it's a middleware, it should call itself pretty often already. Otherwise you could use vuex' `watch` method and watch `store.getters.authenticated` old vs new value: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have missed your comment. Personally, that approach feels kind of off. The store shouldn't be responsible for checking permissions and redirect, thats what middleware is designed for in nuxt. I ended up doing 'this.$router.go()`, and refresh the page to rerun he middleware. Changing permissions means you have done a major change (switching accounts or logging out) in which case a refresh is totally reasonable and less error prone.

Comment: Yep, happens to me sometimes too. Did not get notified even if following a post (sometimes hopefully). Hope it's not a global SO bug. Posted an answer, this way you'll probably see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked how to rerun it inside of the middleware itself, which is the 2nd part of a possible middleware trigger (like if the user is not authenticated anymore while staying on the same page) and without any specific action, like when using polling or websockets I thought.

Meanwhile, the 1st part is the easiest: call the middleware globally (in `nuxt.config.js`) to trigger it on each page navigation.
If he stays on the same page, you can also move with the router as you did but at this point, checking if there is an error in your axios is maybe more appropriate since it's the initiator.

I also do like to use `this.$nuxt.refresh()` to trigger all the checks when switching accounts globally, helps re-running all those tasty `fetch()` hooks.

Comment: Is there a call like `this.$nuxt.refresh()` in Nuxt 3? `refreshNuxtData` doesn't re-run middlewares. `reloadNuxtApp` reloads everything from server, that's a bit too much/slow.